# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: reactjs

I want to copy the contents of an HTML table. 
The code to copy the table is:

```
copyTable(){
    let item = this.refs.exportData.outerText\\data in the table
    this.copyData(item)
}

copyData(item){

if (item) {
    if (document.selection) { // IE
      var range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(item));
      range.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(document.getElementById(item));
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
      document.execCommand('copy');
  }
}
```

I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." in the line of code  `range.selectNode(document.getElementById(item));`.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Following this line:

`let item = this.refs.exportData.outerText`

`item` is a `string` and not a DOM node while you're using it later on in a `document.getElementById`. 
`

```
//item is a DOM Node
let item = this.refs.exportData
/* ... */
range.selectNode(item);
```

Comment: item is already a DOM node, my mistake. I edited my answer. A `getElementById` is therefore not needed.

Comment: solved my problem too, thank you! `[+1]`